# Shoutcast 2.5 mIRC Socket Bot Connection Problem

Tags: sockets, irc, shoutcast, internet-radio, mirc

I have a socket bot that I use as a radio, but it cannot pull the data and reflect it to the channel. What is the problem?

```
sockwrite -nt $sockname GET $+(/admin.cgi?pass=,$_rpass,&sid=1&mode=viewxml&page=0) HTTP/1.1
sockwrite -nt $sockname Host: $+($_rip, :, $_rport)
sockwrite -nt $sockname User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040614 Firefox/0.8
sockwrite -nt $sockname Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
sockwrite -nt $sockname Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
sockwrite -nt $sockname Keep-Alive: 300
sockwrite -nt $sockname Connection: keep-alive
sockwrite -nt $sockname $crlf
```

Comment: Wow, haven't seen this sort of thing in awhile!  Can you run a packet sniffer like Wireshark where the bot is running so you can see what's actually happening on the wire?  First thought is, I'm wondering about your password.  Is it using any reserved characters that can't normally go in the URL?

Comment: Hi Brad, thank you so much for your concern.

It was a mIRC Socket bot on the server that I reflected the names of the music playing on the radio channel and how many people listened to it.
But after the shoutcast 2.5 version, it started not pulling the data.

My password is still on the same remote;

alias $_rpass return password

attached in the form

and it's trying to pull data from the XML file as a source. If you want to look at the whole code, I can post it.

Comment: Just, use Wireshark to get a packet capture so you can see what the actual problem is.  I don't have anywhere to run your code, and don't have any SHOUTcast v2 servers running at the moment.  It's easier to teach you how to debug it than it is to reproduce the problem.  If you just had this problem after upgrading, SHOUTcast v2.5 probably just doesn't support the format you need anymore.  But, check what's actually happening with the HTTP request/response to be sure.

Comment: What seems to be the error\issue?